# Never did +1 but have hundreds of +1's in my Google account data

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1, malware

I have a Google account but I use it mostly for Gmail, never had any activity in Google+ and didn't +1 anything ever.

Today I went to the account data page to review / disable some things and the page seemed to be saying that I +1'd over 800 times!

[image: wtf.png]

And the +1 tab in my profile was empty. Well, it was *almost* empty, there was one entry related to Skype Wifi, and I didn't do that either.

Do I have a malware? Could it be done by some malicious JavaScript when I visited a website(s)?

Answer (score 3):

The +1 tab on your Google+ profile is strictly website URLs you have +1'd. This number includes a variety of things including but not limited to: +1'ing website URL's, +1'ing posts or comments on Google+, as well as liking YouTube comments.